# Angular - How a destroy a Dynamically component by a button click

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I am using this to dynamically create a component in angular:

```
addComponent() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
    const viewContainerRef = this.injectComp.viewContainerRef;
    const compRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    compRef.instance.someProperty = "some data";
}
```

So each time the method is executed a new instance of the component is created.
Up to there, all is great but my question is:

How do I destroy these created components from the ChildComponent itself with a button click event?

Comment: Self close means -- you want to destroy the components ?

Comment: Yes, if I create 5 components (for example) ... I want to be able to click on a button on the component and self destroy it

Comment: Check this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354312/how-to-remove-a-component-dynamically-in-angular-6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a component dynamically in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354312/how-to-remove-a-component-dynamically-in-angular-6)

Comment: This is not how I want to do it. I want to trigger a self destroy on the childComponent itself. Can it be done?

Comment: A trigger can only happen if a event is done or using any setTimeout.

Comment: Yes, suppose the component has a close button: <div (click)="closeme()">I am a component</div> ... I want to be able to destroy it

Comment: The above link clearly states that you have to take a reference to that component and you have to destory that component reference on button click. Try that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can keep track of component or all component in a variable or in a object and destroy them:-

2) Or, destroy previous component when loading new one in DOM by storing last reference and `.destroy()` them before inserting new one.

## .html

```
 <ng-container #dynamicComponentContainer id="dynamicComponentContainer"></ng-container>
```

## .ts

```
         let componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(cmptName).create(this.injector);

                // check for duplicates and update with new one
             //   this.checkForDuplicateCmp(componentRef);

                componentRef.instance['inputdata'] = initCmpInputdata;
                let indexView = this.dynamicComponentContainer.length;
                this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(componentRef.hostView, indexView);

      // keep refrence of lastComponent added to DOM
            this.lastComponent = componentRef;


  public remove component(){
    // destroy components as on click
      this.lastComponent.destroy();
     //or
     for (var j = 1; j < this.dynamicComponentContainer.length; j++) {
          this.dynamicComponentContainer.remove(j);  //or pass j 
      }
}
```