# How to use DynamicModule.withComponents of ng-dynamic-component without creating dependency for those components?

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular-dynamic-components

I have 3 modules with a component in each:

```
tasks
  >tasks
    -tasks.component.ts|html|css
  -tasks.module.ts

people
  >people
    -people.component.ts|html|css
  -people.module.ts

dynamic-container
  >dynamic-container
    -dynamic-container.component.ts|html|css
  -dynamic-container.module.ts
```

and I'm using [ng-dynamic-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component) package to set tasks, people and in future some other components dynamically to DynamicContainerComponent.

dynamic-container.html

```
<div *ngFor="let dynComponent of dynComponents()">
   <ndc-dynamic [ndcDynamicComponent]="dynComponent.component">
   </ndc-dynamic>
</div>
```

array dynComponents looks like this:

```
public dynComponents: ITabComponent[] = [
   { name: 'Tasks', icon: 'tasks', component: TasksComponent },
   { name: 'People', icon: 'people', component: PeopleComponent }
];
```

Now this already creates dependency to TasksModule and PeopleModule, but in addition DynamicContainerModule looks like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DynamicContainerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TasksModule,
    PeopleModule,
    DynamicModule.withComponents([TasksComponent, PeopleComponent])
  ],
  exports: [DynamicContainerComponent]
})
export class DynamicContainerModule { }
```

So how can I remove those dependencies and make DynamicContainerComponent truly dynamic? I guess I could create additional module which is application specific and which returns the dynComponents array (i don't know how to do even this correctly), but the DynamicModule.withComponents part is even more tricky.

Comment: Hope this article can help you. https://blog.angularindepth.com/building-extensible-dynamic-pluggable-enterprise-application-with-angular-aed8979faba5

Comment: I know, it's been a long time, but have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) instead of ng-dynamic-components.

And you can load the component and remove the component based on conditions.[dynamically loading a component](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjjyrlbkyral).(example is kept on set timeout, but you can call the function on the condition from a service or backend as you like.)

In the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52354498/10179262) You can find how to remove a component dynamically.

Comment: thanks, but i'm asking a solution to a specific issue

Comment: i don't know if it was possible or not the way i tried to do it, but  dynamic component loader works. it's not simple though. thanks!